# Open pdf file with Apex 5.1

Tags: oracle-apex

I'm using (recently) Apex 5.1 and I want simply open a pdf file in browser or with acrobat reader. 
I have a field with the correct link and I want to open file on click.
I tried to write this in pre-text on advanced features of the item-field: 
`<a href="&LINKCOLUMN.">` and naturally i close the tag `</a>` in post text space.
It seems work, because if i get over with my mouse pointer, in the info bar of browser i can see the correct link: `file:///N:/DOCS/filename.pdf`
If i try to copy link and paste in another tab, it works perfectly, but if I click with mouse, it don't work. Seems something works, but the page dont' change nothing. 
I think the problem is that files are stored in networked folder and apex have some security restriction, but if i need to open in this path, is there a solution?

Thanks for answer and sorry for my english. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not apex. Browsers do not allow it (although IE may be the exception) because of security concerns. Sure, it works by opening it directly (because it starts with a file directive), but navigation to it will not work (eg from http to file).

You can 'solve' it by exposing the folder through an http server such as apache. Plenty of documentation on that, I'm not expert in that domain.

Answer (score 0):

What I've done in the past is this:

1. Store the PDF as a blob
2. Create an application process to download the file.

For the application process..
Process point: on load before header.
Type: pl/sql

Process text:

```
Begin
  Schema.download_my_file([some file number]);
End;
```

Conditions: request = expression1

Expression 1: DOWNLOAD_FILE

Have a look at the download_my_file procedure found in oracle's documentation:

[oracle doc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14373_01/appdev.32/e13363/up_dn_files.htm#CIHDDJGF)

You may wish to tweak oracle's procedure to meet your needs.. example: you may wish to change the content disposition to inline vs attachment.

Using this method I've been able to successfully display PDFs inline within the browser. Remember to set your button's request to match the condition of your application process.

Comment: This -could- be a possible workaround, though it's often not feasible to move files over to blobs in the database (what if we're talking gigabytes worth of files, for example). Another method could be to create an oracle directory on the database which is put on the remote directory, and through which the files can be fetched and served as a download through the database. Again, also a workaround, and it puts extra load on your database (cpu, ram). If a drive simply has be enabled for http, a webserver would be the best solution, imo.

Comment: In fact, the problem is that i have to store many gigabytes of pdf files... I'm tryng to use apache now and it seem to works.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone in the future that want to work with files (upload and download), I'm recommending using Oracle sample from Create --> Productivity App --> Sample file upload

It is short and you can find all the answers there.